# TimeSpan.TryParseExact not working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve a timespan from a string, but TryParseExact is returning false (fail).

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, can you help? I've tried 2 versions of my line in the code, both do not work.

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact("04:00:01","HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out aTime)
```

and

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact("04:00:01","HH:mm:ss", null, out aTime)
```

EDIT:
both responses here are correct, I have the wrong format for my custom timespan format - the mistake I made is to assume that the custom formats for DateTime would work for TimeSpans, but they do not.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The problem is simply in the format string for the TimeSpan, you have specified `"HH:mm:ss"`.  The specifier `HH` (upper case) is not valid for timespan.  You should use `hh`.  Format strings are indeed case sensitive.

The colon character (`:`) also needs to be escaped, so use `"hh\\:mm\\:ss"`, `@"hh\:mm\:ss"` or `"hh':'mm':'ss"`.  All three forms will have the same effect.

You can review a list of valid custom format strings for TimeSpan [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee372287.aspx). and the standard format strings for TimeSpan are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee372286.aspx).

While `HH` is valid for DateTime and DateTimeOffset where it represents the 24 hour clock and lower case hh represents a 12 hour clock, For TimeSpan - the hours component is always based on 24 hours.  You would think that the `HH` format would be the one chosen, for uniformity, but nope - it's `hh`.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise that the custom strings for DateTime and TimeSpan were different.

Comment: Yes "HH:mm:ss" returns false. I had also to scape colon characters like Oğuz Yıldız say. Then, my format is "hh\\:mm\\:ss". It's a combination of the two answers.

Comment: Is the difference noted somewhere in the docs? That would be a greater mistake than having different format specifies.

Comment: 12-hour or 24-hour clocks aren't really applicable here. TimeSpan indicates a _duration_, not a time of day, so any number of hours is acceptable, including more than 24.

Comment: @teedyay - While `TimeSpan` does indeed represent *duration*, its parsing functions will not allow hours to be more than 23.  You will get an `OverflowException`.  This is in [the msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/se73z7b9.aspx) (the second item listed under `OverflowException`), and you can see it easily if you try something like `TimeSpan.Parse("24:00")` or `TimeSpan.ParseExact("24:00", "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.  So, it is indeed applicable.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with escaped colons. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably should get mentioned that you need to escape the colon character.

```
TryParseExact("04:00:01", "HH\\:mm\\:ss" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The string format which you are passing is wrong.

```
var res=TimeSpan.TryParseExact("04:00:01", "g", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out aTime);
```

g- General short format and is culture sensitive.

More on this here [Standard Timespan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx)

Comment: ok, but I've provided a custom format string, why doesn't that work?

Comment: i have tried this and its working.what exactly is not working for you

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and yes it does work, but I'd still like to understand why mine did not.

Comment: A standard TimeSpan format string accepts a  single format specifier to define the text representation of a TimeSpan value that results from a formatting operation.- MSDN.Please have alook at the link that i have given above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were using multiple formats.

```
public const string TimeFormat1 = "hh\\:mm";
public const string TimeFormat2 = "hh\\:mm:\\ss";
var parsed = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(time, new [] { TimeFormat1, TimeFormat2 }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out TimeSpan ts1);
// parsed is always false
```

You might have thought you escaped your colon; but didn't, actually...

This `"hh\\:mm:\\ss"` won't work.

Using TimeFormat2 in ParseExact throws a FormatException...

You meant to use this `"hh\\:mm\\:ss"` instead.