# TimeSpan.ParseExact() returns false for apparently valid format

Tags: c#, timespan

Why does this code return false? [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042675/489560) **strongly** implies that it should return true.

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact("04:00:01", "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out x);
```

Using `InvariantCulture` also returns false and `TimeSpan.ParseExact()` throws an invalid format exception. `HH:mm:ss` is wrong, as per the above question.

How is `04:00:01` breaking the format for `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: What is the current culture for you?

Comment: `en-US` is the current culture. Like I said, using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` has the same results.

Comment: If you exclusively used invariant in the question it'd be fine, but when you refer to the current culture the current culture becomes relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `@"hh\:mm\:ss"` for your format.

Comment: Exactly, here is a link on [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

Comment: There is even a nice big "Important" box at the start of that link explaining this.